# What are the nights in the Eric Clapton's 24 nights album?

Tags: rock, blues, album

My favorite Eric Clapton's album is the 24 nights. I wonder what specifically the 24 nights are? I know some of them, say blues nights or orchestra nights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_Nights):

> The album is a "best of" from the 42 concerts Eric Clapton did at the
>   Royal Albert Hall in those two years. **Clapton set a record by playing
>   a run of 24 nights at the London Royal Albert Hall between 5 February
>   and 9 March 1991**, following an 18-night run in 1990.

You can check out [set lists for each date](http://www.whereseric.com/eric-clapton-tour/archive/1991) on this website, including the line-up of the band for each night.